# operator overloading constraints in c#

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

Q) why 'public' & 'static' is necessary in operator overloading in C#?

tried this article

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/why-are-overloaded-operators-always-static-in-c

But could someone explain what the author is trying to say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author makes a simple cost/benefit analysis of a potential feature of operator overloading in a non-static way, and concludes that the benefits do not justify the costs: you can easily mimic the functionality of instance overloading of operators by dispatching to a virtual method from inside of a statically overloaded operator. However, the costs of letting you define overloaded operators without an intermediate virtual functions are great:

- You introduce asymmetry in the way your operators work (`2+c` may be illegal while `c+2` is OK)
- You need to deal with `null` references on the left-hand side
- Single dispatch would not address your problem anyway, so you'd end up doing additional dispatch work inside the operator

At the end, the author notes that rather than introducing a feature that introduces much confusion without a significant benefit, they went for a cleaner design that can be extended to provide comparable levels of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Public is necessary so that it can be accessed outside of the class.
Static is necessary as not calling it on the instance of the class.

```
public class B {
    public static B operator+(B b1, B b2) { return b1.Add(b2); }
    protected virtual B Add(B b2) { // ...
```

For the above example i can have code like `b3 = b1 + b2`, here + operator is not called on either instance of the class B, so it need to be static.
Hope this helps.